# What is the technology used behind Inshorts,Dailyhunt and other such news apps how does it work?

Tags: android, web-applications, android-applicationinfo

I want to know how does the news apps like Dailyhunt,Inshorts and others work.How and where do they upload the news and how the users are able to get the news on their android app.Please answer this and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> How and where do they upload the news?

Backend server. Each one has tie up with content provider to get the data e.g tie-up with different newspaper etc.

> how the users are able to get the news on their android app?

Android app communicate with their backend server to get the data and display it for user.